# Ejecutar una función dentro de otra función en un objeto literal de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones, javascript-objeto

Soy muy nueva trabajando con objetos en JavaScript y me encontré con este ejercicio que no puedo resolver por la siguiente cuestión: Dentro del objeto, **¿Cómo se puede ejecutar una función que depende de otra para que entregue un resultado?**

En mi código tengo que exportar un arreglo de objetos llamado **`autos`** el cual después forma parte del objeto **`consesionaria`**, posteriormente se tienen que crear una serie de funciones como *busquedaPorPatente* que arroja el objeto que contenga la patente que se pide, otra llamada *buscarAuto* que entrega el auto si la **`patente`** coincide o, de lo contrario, muestra un **`null`** *(aquí estoy repitiendo mi código en ambas funciones, lo cual tengo entendido no es del todo correcto y podría simplificarse)*, después viene la función *venderAuto* que nuevamente recibe la **`patente`** , y en caso de encontrar al automóvil, le asigna el estado de vendido. Podría, otra vez, repetir el código usado en la función anterior pero, **¿Hay una manera de llamar a esa función para no tener que escribir un código que ya hice?**

Pensé en un **`if`** pero lo único que me muestra es un **`false`** en lugar de todas las propiedades del objeto con el cambio, es decir:

> ```
> {
>   marca: 'Ford',
>   modelo: 'Fiesta',
>   precio: 150000,
>   km: 200,
>   color: 'Azul',
>   cuotas: 12,
>   anio: 2019,
>   patente: 'APL123',
>   vendido: true
> }
> ```

Este es mi arreglo de objetos:

```
let autos=[
    {marca:"Ford", modelo: "Fiesta", precio: 150000, km:200, color: "Azul", cuotas: 12, anio: 2019, patente:"APL123", vendido: false},
    {marca:"Toyota", modelo: "Corolla", precio: 100000, km:0, color: "Blanco", cuotas: 14, anio: 2019, patente:"JJK116", vendido: false}
];

module.exports = autos;
```

Y este el código donde debo realizar las diferentes funciones:

```
const autos = require('./autos');

const concesionaria = {
    autos: autos,

    BusquedaPorPatente:function(patente){
        for (let i= 0; i<autos.length; i++){
            if (autos[i].patente == patente){
                return autos[i]
            }
        }
    },

    buscarAuto:function(patente){
        for (let i= 0; i<autos.length; i++){
            if (autos[i].patente === patente){
                return autos[i]
            }
            else {
                return null
            }
        }
    },

    venderAuto: function(patente) {
       if (this.buscarAuto(patente) === patente){
           return autos[i].vendido===true

        }
    }
    
};

console.log(concesionaria.venderAuto("APL123"));
```

Espero puedan aclararme un poco el tema ya que no he encontrado mucha información al respecto más allá de los temas básicos de objetos literales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien el problema tienes los siguientes tres métodos para el objeto `concesionaria`:

1. `busquedaPorPatente`: retorna el auto al que pertenezca la patente. No mencionas lo que se devuelve si no se encuentra la patente por lo que el comportamiento de JS será retornar `undefined`.
2. `buscarAuto`: lo mismo que el método anterior solo que si no se encuentra la pantente, este devolverá `null`. Este método no tiene mucho sentido, puesto que es lo mismo que el primero.
3. `venderAuto`: hará uso de alguno de los dos métodos anteriores para hacer la búsqueda y en caso de encontrarlo, esteblecer la propiedad `vendido = true`.

Asumiendo que los puntos anteriores son correctos, tu método `buscarPorPatente` está correcto.

Luego para el punto número dos, puedes llamar al método `busquedaPorPatente` usando `this`, asignar el resultado en una variable y evaluar si existe para saber si retornar el objeto o el valor `null`.

Para el punto número tres es un poco más de lo mismo. Estás obteniendo `false` porque al utilizar triple igual (`===`) no haces una asignación, haces una comparación, estás evaluando `false === true` por lo que obtienes `false`.

```js
let autos = [
  { marca: "Ford", modelo: "Fiesta", precio: 150000, km: 200, color: "Azul", cuotas: 12, anio: 2019, patente: "APL123", vendido: false },
  { marca: "Toyota", modelo: "Corolla", precio: 100000, km: 0, color: "Blanco", cuotas: 14, anio: 2019, patente: "JJK116", vendido: false }
];

const concesionaria = {
  autos: autos,
  busquedaPorPatente: function (patente) {
    for (let i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
      if (autos[i].patente === patente) {
        return autos[i]
      }
    }
  },
  buscarAuto: function (patente) {
    const auto = this.busquedaPorPatente(patente);
    return auto ? auto : null;
  },
  venderAuto: function (patente) {
    const auto = this.buscarAuto(patente);
    if (auto) {
      auto.vendido = true;
    }
  }
};

console.log(concesionaria.autos);
console.log(concesionaria.venderAuto("APL123"));
console.log(concesionaria.autos);
```

Comment: Ah ya veo. Dentro de la función venderAuto creaste la constante auto y a esa le asignaste la función busquedaPorPatente para luego usar el if. Eso es lo que mi cerebro no entendía ¡Muchas gracias! Pensaba que tenía que usar un callback o un indexOf pero la solución era más sencilla.

Comment: Le asignas el resultado de la función `busquedaPorPatente`, más no la función como tal. De este modo puedes luego evaluar ese resultado y trabajarlo según sea necesario. Para lo que sí puedes usar `.indexOf()` es para simplificar tu función de búsqueda, tal como te recomendaron en otro comentario, también es posible usar `.find()` que dentro de las entrañas lo que hace es recorrer el array utilizando una estructura de control repetitiva.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no existe diferencia real entre las funciones `BusquedaPorPatente` y `buscarAuto`, el problema que tienes es que estás repitiendo código que no necesita ser repetido. La función `buscarAuto` es en realidad una búsqueda por patente, esto es un error de diseño.

Te recomiendo que utilices una sola función para buscar un auto por patente... Al retornar `null` vas a poder evaluar si el carro realmente existe o no por medio de un `if`, ya que un objeto se evalua como un valor verdadero y por lo tanto se ejecutará lo que está dentro del `if`; y por otro lado no se ejecutará si su condición contiene un valor nulo (`null`).

También aprovecha que estás devolviendo como valor de retorno una referencia al objeto que encontraste y utiliza esta referencia para cambiar las propiedades del objeto, es decir, puedes guardar la referencia del carro que encontraste (en el ejemplo lo hago con una variable llamada `auto` con la cuál luego puedo editar su propiedad `vendido`.

```js
let autos = [{
    marca: "Ford",
    modelo: "Fiesta",
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: "Azul",
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "APL123",
    vendido: false
  },
  {
    marca: "Toyota",
    modelo: "Corolla",
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: "Blanco",
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "JJK116",
    vendido: false
  }
];

const concesionaria = {
  autos: autos,

  busquedaPorPatente: function(patente) {
    for (let i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
      if (autos[i].patente == patente) {
        return autos[i]
      }else
      return null;
    }
  },
  
  //Tu funcion busquedaPorAuto es igual que busqueda por patente, no necesitas dos funciones que hagan
  //Lo mismo si no tienen ninguna diferencia entre sí
  
  venderAuto: function(patente) {
    //Busca el carro haciendo referencia a la función anterior por medio de "this"
    const auto = this.busquedaPorPatente(patente);
    
    //Si existe entonces cambiemos su propiedad de vendido, no necesitamos retornar ningún valor
    if (auto) {
      //Para cambiar una propiedad usa el operador de asignación (=) no el de comparación (===)
      auto.vendido = true

    }
  }

};

console.log("Vehículo APL123 antes de hacer la venta:");
console.log(concesionaria.busquedaPorPatente("APL123"));
console.log("Se realiza la venta del vehículo");
concesionaria.venderAuto("APL123");
console.log("Vehículo APL123 después de hacer la venta:");
console.log(concesionaria.busquedaPorPatente("APL123"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya tienes dos muy buenas respuestas que explican porque no funciona correctamente tu código y esta propuesta es para ampliar un poco la funcionalidad:

1. El método `buscarAuto()` puede servirte para buscar por cualquier propiedad por medio de [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), que devuelve el primer elemento que cumple con la condición o, si no hay coincidencias, devuelve `undefined`
2. El método `busquedaPorPatente()` llama a `buscarAuto()`, enviando la propiedad y el valor que se desea buscar; esto te permitiría crear otros métodos como `busquedaPorMarca()` que, aunque el nombre de función es más largo, también es más intuitivo sobre la tarea a realizar
3. El método `venderAuto()` buscará el auto por patente y devolverá un texto, de acuerdo a si existe el auto y puede venderse o no

```js
let autos = [
    {marca:"Ford", modelo: "Fiesta", precio: 150000, km:200, color: "Azul", cuotas: 12, anio: 2019, patente:"APL123", vendido: false},
    {marca:"Toyota", modelo: "Corolla", precio: 100000, km:0, color: "Blanco", cuotas: 14, anio: 2019, patente:"JJK116", vendido: false}
];

const concesionaria = {
    autos: autos,
    // Buscar auto por propiedad (marca, modelo, patente, etc.) y valor
    buscarAuto: function(prop, value) {
        // El método .find() es mejor que un ciclo
        // Devuelve la primera coincidencia o undefined si no encuentra
        return autos.find(auto => auto[prop] == value);
    },
    busquedaPorPatente: function(patente) {
        return this.buscarAuto('patente', patente);
    },
    venderAuto: function(patente) {
        // Buscar por patente
        const auto = this.busquedaPorPatente(patente);
        // ¿No existe el auto?
        if(!auto) {
            return 'El auto no existe, no se puede vender.';
        }
        // ¿Fue vendido previamente?
        if(auto.vendido) {
            return 'No se puede vender un auto vendido previamente.'
        }
        // Sí existe y no ha sido vendido
        // Marcar como vendido
        auto.vendido = true;
        return 'El auto fue vendido correctamente.';
    }
};

// Este auto se puede vender
console.log(concesionaria.venderAuto("APL123"));
// Este auto no existe
console.log(concesionaria.venderAuto("ABC123"));
// No puedes vender un auto que ya fue vendido
console.log(concesionaria.venderAuto("APL123"));
```

Comment: muchas gracias, jamás se me hubiera pasado por la cabeza usar if (!auto) o (auto.vendido). Normalmente veía y utilizaba  if comparando 2 variables o utilizando operadores y números. También voy a seguir tu consejo de usar .find() en lugar de un for :)